# Fetch values from a table using jquery on basis of a checkbox update

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I fetched date using API and displaying it in a table using [this](http://prntscr.com/awhpb7) code:

This resulted in 176 values with a `checkbox`. Now I want that if a `checkbox` state is changed then I should be able to fetch the value and an associated td value in an array. Can someone help me as I am not able to think of any solution.

[Here](http://prntscr.com/awhqes) is a screenshot of output along with what I want to achieve:

Comment: add your rendered html

Comment: good way to ask question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest giving each td element with an associated value a class, so that you can use jQuery to grab the value.  Suppose we gave the class name of 'value'.  Then, you could probably try something like this:

```
$('checkbox').on('click', getValue);

function getValue() {
    var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('.value').text();
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Brett, Thank you for the suggestion, it did the work, though it also gave sense to me to look into it further and I found that we can also use following code: $('.boxt').change(function(){
    var xy = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').text();